# Iterm2 print console log like chrome debug tools

Tags: logging, iterm2

Is there any way or tool to print out the real time logs from a react app like Chrome debug tool.

I personally use iterm2 on my mac but following the regular console logs is not easy at all. Would be great if there is a tool or way to handle the logs, if they are objects for example, so you can click and expand step by step. Just like chrome debugger.